# What determines Z-Index in a Google Geochart?

Tags: google-visualization, z-index

I am trying to plot yearly data on a geochart. I would like the most recent data on top, but for whatever reason, the earliest year is always on top in the actual visualization.

I have tried re-ordering the table to have the latest years as the first entries in the data with no effect.

I thought that maybe it was happening because I used a view to filter my data, but the filter is not reordering the items with the older ones first (so that shouldn't impact how it is displayed).

I do not want to filter out data since I use transparency to display all points. Here is some sample code that displays the same problem:

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Latitude');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Longitude');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Color');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Output (MW)');
    data.addRows([
      [35, 135, 2, 334],
      [35, 135, 1, 100],
      [35.1, 135.1, 1, 100],
      [35.1, 135, 1, 100],
      [35, 135.1, 1, 100],
      [34.9, 134.9, 1, 100],
      [34.9, 135, 1, 100],
      [35, 135.1, 1, 100],
  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, {
    colorAxis: {
      'minValue': 1,
      'maxValue': 2,
      'values': [1, 2],
      'colors': ['black','red'],
    },
    'markerOpacity': 0.5,
    'region': 'JP'
  });
}
```

I can change the values in column 2 or 3 (0-indexed), or I can change the order of the entries in to the data table, but I keep getting the same result. I have a feeling it always sticks bigger sized values in the back so you can still see the little values, but I'm wondering if there is any authoritative reference on it, or any way to get around it.

This is what it looks like no matter what I do:

> [image: Google Visualization Results]

What I want it to look like is as follows (manipulated the SVG manually to adjust the Z-order):

> [image: Manually Manipulated Z-Order]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with it for a bit, and I think you're right: it's automatically z-indexing the markers in size-order.  If I read your intent correctly, you are looking to show some subset of years, and you want the markers to be z-indexed by years.  I think you can accomplish that with some custom filtering: sort your data by location and year, then for every location, filter out every year with a smaller size than any of the newer years.  Something like this should work:

```
// order by location and year (descending)
var rows = data.getSortedRows([0, 1, {column: 2, desc: true}]);
// parse the rows backwards, removing all years where a location has a newer year with a larger size value
// we don't need to parse row 0, since that will always be the latest year for some location
var size, lat, long;
for (var i = rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    size = data.getValue(rows[i], 3);
    lat = data.getValue(rows[i], 0);
    long = data.getValue(rows[i], 1);
    for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0 && lat == data.getValue(rows[j], 0) && long == data.getValue(rows[i], 1); j--) {
        if (size < data.getValue(rows[j], 3)) {
            rows.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(rows);
```

Here's a working example based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/36AmD/

Comment: Unfortunately, this actually eliminates some of the data (which isn't my intention since I use semi-transparency to visualize all points at the same time).

Comment: I can see that with your edited post.  I'd suggest hitting up the [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) page to formalize the suggestion dlaliberte made about an option to turn off z-index reordering.

Comment: Thanks asgallant, I'll take a look at that. Looks like most of the items on the list are owned by dlaliberte -- I know you're active on there too. Hopefully these get fixed at some time in the future (or I can start picketing their offices -- *"Arbitrary z-indexing is a sin!"*

Comment: Well, you've got at a part of the giant Google mega-brain thinking about the problem, but if you feel the need to picket and are in the Boston area, I'll show up to give you moral support.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the order of the markers is determined by the size, with the larger markers drawn first so they end up below the smaller markers, which is a convenience for most applications.  If you wish to hide 'later' markers based on order, you'll have to do that another way, perhaps by hiding the rows of data.

Is there a reason it makes sense to hide data if it covers 'earlier' data?  Perhaps an option could be added to disable this automatic reordering, especially if transparent colors are used to allow you to see through.

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it Dan!  +1 for option to disable automatic ordering.  Does the API allow transparent colors?  I was under the impression that all colors options take valid HTML color strings (aside from the custom "transparent" color), which don't include any transparency options.

Comment: You can set marker opacity to 0.5, and all markers have a non-transparent border around them. When you have a lot of small markers on top of a larger marker, it looks a lot different than if you reverse the order (through manual manipulation of the SVG).

Answer (score -1):

Try this, helped me in a project:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.google-visualization-table').css("z-index", "1");
}, 500);
```